# Uploading file data into mysql blob type

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, node-mysql

I am using Strongloop application to upload image into mysql database.

I am trying to store image into mysql blob column.
My model configuration for the column is like:

```
"data": {
        "type": "Buffer",
        "mysql": {
            "columnName": "data",
            "dataType": "blob",
            "dataLength": null
        }
    }
```

MySql column is of type 'blob'.

I tried to store the data using 'formidable':

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm({
    keepExtensions: true
});
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    var readData = fs.readFileSync(files.file.path);
    if(!Buffer.isBuffer(readData)){
        readData = new Buffer(readData);
    }
    var input = {
        id: '',
        name: files.file.name,
        type: files.file.type,
        data: readData
    };
    <My-Model>.create(input, function(err, data1){
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send(data1);
    });
});
```

I am getting error in create callback:
message: "ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'data' at row 1"
sqlState: "22001"

It looks create API is treating 'input' as string internally.

Comment: Run your server with debug string `set DEBUG=loopback:connector:mysql && node .` to get more info (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Setting+debug+strings)